# KendoUI Export to excel

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Standard html download contains an msSaveOrOpen capability.  When exporting excel/pdf from KendoUI grid, the dialog is only save, then a 2nd dialog opens with "open   save"  etc.

How can I get the excel export to open using open/save buttons instead of just save?

Comment: This is at least partially controlled by the browser.  Certain browsers, no matter what you do will only offer save.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is a browser feature. You can change this in the advanced settings in Chrome.

[image]